# IP camera HK vision url streaming in vb .net

Tags: vb.net, sockets, camera, ip, ip-camera

```
  Dim mjpegSource As New MJPEGStream("rtsp://192.0.0.64:554/cam[CHANNEL]/mjpeg")
            mjpegSource.Login = "admin"
            mjpegSource.Password = ""
        VideoSourcePlayer1.VideoSource = mjpegSource
```

error is the url prefix is not recognized this is how i fixed but with vlc can streaming

Answer (score 0):

`MJPEGStream` expects that the feed is Motion JPEG over HTTP. This is basically HTTP request/response where camera infinitely sends a sequence of JPEG images over established HTTP link.

Your URL starts with `rtsp://` and suggests this is identifier of RTSP compliant resource. The camera sends data in conformance with RTSP protocol, RTP payload for Motion JPEG encoding.

RTSP identifier, protocol, connection is incompatible with `MJPEGStream` class.